# Redux state variable undefined in useEffect return function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

A variable fetched from Redux state by useSelector is undefined in useEffect return function:

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const stateVariable = useSelector(state => state.variable);
    console.log(stateVariable) // undefined on first render, then "whatever"

    useEffect(() => {
        // set state on component mount using a generic action creator
        dispatch(setStateVariable("whatever")); 
        
        return () => {
            console.log(stateVariable) // undefined on unmount
        }
    }, []); // leave empty so it runs only on mount/unmount

    return null;
}
```

Why is stateVariable undefined in the cleanup function?
How can I use stateVariable in the cleanup function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can anchor your value using `useRef` to have access to its value on cleanup function. You get `undefined` because of closure, where your function saves the reference value once is declared:

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const stateVariable = useSelector(state => state.variable);
  const stateRef = useRef();
  stateRef.current = stateVariable;
  console.log(stateVariable); // undefined on first render, then "whatever"

  useEffect(() => {
      // set state on component mount using a generic action creator
      dispatch(setStateVariable("whatever")); 
      
      return () => {
          console.log(stateRef.current);
      }
  }, []); // leave empty so it runs only on mount/unmount

  return null;
}
```